# Allow only one checkbox to be checked in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a list that is bound to a datagrid, a property of the items is a boolean and is bound to a checkbox in the datagrid.

[image]

How can I allow only one checkbox to be selected?

For example, if one checkbox is selected, then the other checkboxes should be unselected.

What I have tried so far (in the ViewModel, Update is the boolean property):

```
var update = item.Update;
Items.ForEach(x => x.Update = false);
Items = new List<Item>(Items);
item.Update = update;
```

But this not efficient and it throws an Exception that the list was modified (collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute).

Is there an efficient way to get the job done?

Edit: I'm using Binding to bind the list, the list is from type List<>, and the items of the list implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Consider using a Radio Button rather than a Checkbox, as users of your application will expect that any Checkbox is multi-select while a Radio Button is single-select. This is purely my opinion of good User Experience, and doesn't necessarily directly address your code/issue.

Comment: If there can only be one row selected then just set that one to false and not all? In such a one-from-many selection i assume also you already know the single one that is selected and don't even need to search for that.

Comment: Are you using data binding? If so, are you using `ObservableCollection`? Do your list members implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`? How is your data grid populated? Please show some of this code.

Comment: If you're using `ObservableCollection` and collection items implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` you don't need `Items = new List<Item>(Items);`

Answer (score 0):

I've commented the issue that you have in this code:

```
var update = item.Update;
Items.ForEach(x => x.Update = false);
Items = new List<Item>(Items); //This creates a new, empty Items list
item.Update = update; //this item relates to an item in the collection that no longer exists
```

You should have `ObservableCollection<Items> Items` so that if you add/remove items from your list the Binding will follow and `Item` implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`. As `ObservableCollection` doesn't support `ForEach` your code becomes:

```
    var update = item.Update;
    foreach(var element in Items)
    {
        element.Update=false;
    }
    item.Update = update;
```

Comment: Thank you for you solution, but it throws InvalidOperationException: collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Comment: I'm surprised as I tested this code. Please show your datagrid definition with row binding, the view model with class with your `Items` list and the code that calls the above code.